# Is entity key in memcache the same as in datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

When I set the key of a memcache entity like this

```
 syncCache.put(entityKey, entity);
```

where

```
 entityKey = entity.getKey();
 entityKeyIdFromDataStore = entityKey.getId();
```

and afterwards I retrieve the entity stored in memcache and retrieve the key id

```
 entity = (Entity) syncCache.get(entityKey);
 entityKeyIdFromCache = entity.getKey().getId();
```

will entityKeyIdFromDataStore and entityKeyIdFromCache be the same then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will be the same. Note that you can use an ID instead of a key:

```
syncCache.put(entityKey.getId(), entity);
entity = (Entity) syncCache.get(entityKey.getId());
```

An ID is much shorter than a key. This, of course, only works with entities that don't have parents, or if you store only one entity kind in Memcache.